# Is it faster to insert null values on db or to test if it is null and not insert?

Tags: python, postgresql

Im using python and postgresql. I have a lot of colums that are default null. Is it faster to insert null values or test if rhe values are not null and only insert in that case? The query is one big query that will insert in a table with over 500 columns at once. Some of the colums will be null and others wont. Should I only include inthat query colums that are not null or I can use a query with all colums and some of them null?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To be absolutely sure, I would recommend implementing both types -- perhaps roped off with a command line option or environment variable -- and then *benchmark* the results.

However, you can combine the two in a pure *Postgres* manner if you structure the *INSERT* as a *SELECT*.

i.e. something of the form:

```
INSERT INTO foo
SELECT bar
FROM baz
WHERE bar IS NOT NULL;
```

That will almost certainly be faster than two separate queries via, say, *psycopg2*, one to see if NULL, and the another to do the insert.

Re-reading your post, you mentioned having many columns, some of which may be NULL, and others not. You could construct dynamic SQL client-side based on each column, and only *INSERT* those columns. If you had all of those values on hand (i.e. you don't need to make additional database queries to get them), then it may help to construct the INSERT dynamically containing just those columns. However, it's not clear that it would be worth the additional coding effort.

The bigger tradeoff would be *INSERT* at all or no *INSERT*. So if, say, all the you had a couple columns and could check if they were null to avoid the *INSERT*, that would probably be better. Checking, say, 500 columns, that's much less clear, considering how many comparisons that would require.

What I would recommend specifically for the 500 column case is this:

Do the *INSERT* with the values you want to *INSERT*, regardless of whether they are NULL or not, and evaluate the performance. If the performance is acceptable, there's no need to further optimize at that point. If the performance isn't so great, then it's worth taking some steps to optimize, perhaps starting with the client-side dynamic construction of the query filtering out NULL values from the *INSERT*.

As an aside: 500 columns in one table? That may suggest that some *normalization* is in order. (Or is the 500 columns the result of specific **de**-normalization?)

Answer (score 0):

I'd expect it to be quicker to specify all the columns. That way you can `PREPARE` a statement once, and re-use it.

That said, Ken's right: *benchmark and see*.

You know you're getting [uncomfortably close to PostgreSQL's column count limit](http://www.postgresql.org/about/) right? Consider design changes to normalize your data now, before you hit the limit.